# Fatal error using sublime doing web

Tags: php, mysql

f`atal error: Uncaught Error: call to undefined mysql_real_escape_string(),`

i am building a login with sql but keep getting this error can anyone help me please

Comment: show your code which you try, i think you use php 7 so mysql_real_escape_string() not working

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Comment: if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['password_2']);

Answer (score -1):

mysql in PHP is insecure and no longer supported. However, there is a new cass based system called PDO. Here's some basics: Source (https://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/)
Basic Querying

The basic workflow for using the MySQL extension’s functions to work with a database can be thought of as a 5-step process:

```
Establish a connection to the database server and select the database you’ll be working with
Construct a query to send the server
Send the query
Iterate over the returned result rows
Free the resources used by the result and possibly the database connection

<?php
// Step 1: Establish a connection
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "testusr", "secretpass");
mysql_select_db("testdb", $db);

// Step 2: Construct a query
$query = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($zip) . "'";

// Step 3: Send the query
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);

// Step 4: Iterate over the results
while($row = myql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}

// Step 5: Free used resources
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($db);
```

With PDO, the same process can be followed and looks like this:

```
<?php
// Step 1: Establish a connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb", "testusr", "secretpass");

// Step 2: Construct a query
$query = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = " . $db->quote($zip);

// Step 3: Send the query
$result = $db->query($query);

// Step 4: Iterate over the results
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}

// Step 5: Free used resources
$result->closeCursor();
$db = null;
```

Comment: why would you not use bound parameters with pdo, that's the whole point.

Comment: The examples are just pulled from a website. I had no input in it except answering the basic question that was asked.

Comment: any one can goggle and copy and paste, if you dont understand, dont answer.